# Correct SQL Syntax for MariaDB SELECT and Update

Tags: sql, mariadb

I am trying to figure out the correct syntax for a SQL query that is currently in MS SQL Server syntax and needs to be re-written in syntax that will work with MariaDB.

I need to to run a SELECT statement, and then run an update based on the results.

This is what I've tried for the MariaDB re-write:

```
SELECT
  status
FROM
  addynamics.active_status
WHERE
  "table" = "dynamics_time"

IF (status = 3)
    UPDATE
      active_status
    SET
      status = 4
    WHERE
      "table" = 'dynamics_time' 
 END IF;
```

But this is giving me a syntax error. What should this look like?

Answer (score 2):

As i understand your  requirements correct, your statement should looks like:

```
update addynamics.active_status
set  status = 4
WHERE `table` = "dynamics_time" and status=3
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to do two separate things here when you could do them as one. You don't need to SELECT anything to be able to do an UPDATE unless you want to do it before just to make sure you have the right data.

Like Jens @Jens said, doing this would give you the desired results:

```
UPDATE addynamics.active_status
SET STATUS = 4
WHERE `table` = 'dynamics_time' and status = 3
```